# Travis-CI: how to cache composer executable between builds?

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

On every travis build, `composer self-update` is run. And it gets updated on every build. Is it possible to cache composer executables like we do it with `vendor` dir via

```
cache:
  directories:
    - vendor
    - $HOME/.composer/cache
```

I thought about caching the whole `/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.5/bin/composer` but I feel this is not right because the contents of this folder may change without notifying caching system about a change (when travis updates php version for example).

Any suggestions (except for custom composer, of course)?

Comment: I'd be interested as well. It seems only halfway possible by caching all of `$HOME/.composer`. One would also have to do the `composer self-update` in either `install` or `before_install` phase.

Comment: Note: old versions of Composer used `$HOME/.composer/cache` for caches, new versions use `$HOME/.cache/composer/files`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend not updating composer itself, but let travis handle it. (its automatically updated every 30/60 days)

Also i can recommend using the new containerized infrastructure to speed up the runs and allow caching...

```
language: php

sudo: false

cache:
  directories:
        - $HOME/.composer/cache

php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - 7
  - hhvm

install:
  - composer install

script: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

The `sudo: false` statement indicates the use of containers. The `cache:` statement makes sure composer caches correctly.

If you *really* want to cache the composer binary:

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - 7
  - hhvm

cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.composer/cache

install:
  - travis_retry composer self-update && composer --version
  - export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
  - travis_retry composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction

script: vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Also just as a heads up, if testing for HHVM and you need to set the datetime, have a look at https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2523. My way of solving this is adding a `.ini`-file in my `test`-directory with the datetime and setting this in the correct folder for all test-runners. This is prepended in the `install:`-step:

```
  - mkdir -p /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/$(phpenv version-name)/etc/conf.d
  - phpenv config-add test/phpconfig.ini
```

Anyway, a bit more information than you requested, but i hope this helps someone looking for composer/travis/stuff :)